# Return single record per group with max value

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max

I have the following query as a sub query. I need to bring back a single record per `siteid` with the max `grossinternalarea`. Trouble is this doesn't work where there maybe more than one `buildingid` with the same maximum `grossinternalarea`. I have to include the `buildingid` as this is then used in a subsequent join. If you look at the result list you'll see a `siteid` duplicated, rows 3 & 4.
How can I just return one of the buildingIDs? I don't care which one..

```
    SELECT A.SiteID
    , a.buildingid
    , A.BuildYear
    , A.GrossInternalArea

    FROM
    qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea A
    LEFT JOIN qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea B
    ON A.SiteID = B.SiteID AND isnull(A.GrossInternalArea, 0) < isnull(B.GrossInternalArea, 0)
    WHERE
    isnull(A.GrossInternalArea, 0) <> 0
    AND B.GrossInternalArea IS NULL
    ORDER BY
    A.SiteID
    , A.BuildingID
```

[image]

Comment: Is it siteid or buildingID and the image is cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed that subquery in another one and use `row_number`:

```
...
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    A.SiteID ,
                    a.buildingid ,
                    A.BuildYear ,
                    A.GrossInternalArea ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.SiteID ORDER BY A.GrossInternalArea DESC ) rn
          FROM      qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea A
                    LEFT JOIN qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea B ON A.SiteID = B.SiteID
                                                              AND ISNULL(A.GrossInternalArea,
                                                              0) < ISNULL(B.GrossInternalArea,
                                                              0)
          WHERE     ISNULL(A.GrossInternalArea, 0) <> 0
                    AND B.GrossInternalArea IS NULL
        ) t
WHERE   rn = 1
...
```

Comment: Just in case anyone else uses this I took out the order by in the sub query. Amazingly quick answer Giorgi!

Comment: @WelshLady, yes ordering clause would produce error. I had already removed that.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve this is not use this query as a subquery.

Instead of doing:

```
select *
from table1
join subquery
  on ...
```

do

```
select *
from table1 t1
cross apply (
  SELECT 
      top 1 -- need this to filter only one ( the biggest one)
      A.SiteID
    , a.buildingid
    , A.BuildYear
    , A.GrossInternalArea

    FROM
      qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea A
    LEFT JOIN qrySiteBuildingGrossExternalArea B
          ON A.SiteID = B.SiteID AND isnull(A.GrossInternalArea, 0) < isnull(B.GrossInternalArea, 0)
    WHERE
      isnull(A.GrossInternalArea, 0) <> 0
      AND B.GrossInternalArea IS NULL
      and A.SiteID = t1.SiteID  -- you'll need this to link to the outer query
      and A.BuildingID = t1.BuildingID  -- you'll probably need this to link to the outer query
   order by a.GrossInternalArea desc -- use this to get the max one
) xx -- give a name here to use in the query
```